# Unable to alter desired attribute value due to missing model instance in Access/Loaded Hook's context objects(LoopBack3)

Tags: javascript, loopback, angular-loopback

I want to alter an attribute in someModel, whenever a find is called over this model. As I can't use remote Hooks as find is not a remote method, rather built in, and in operational hooks find/findOne only trigger access and loaded hooks, and as my research, they do not return the model instance in their ctx (or if they do, I would like to know where), I want to do something like:

```
modelName.observe('loaded', function (ctx, next) {
      ctx.someModel_instance.updateAttribute(someCount, value
            ,function(err, instance){
             if (err) next(err)
                else{
                      console.log("done")
                 }

      });


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Work Around:**
As `loaded` does not return model instance but it does return `ctx.data`,  in which it returns a copy of the data in your model, If you happen to have a unique `ID` in your model so you can fetch model instance by `findById` and can persistently access/alter the attribute of the said model. e.g:

```
modelName.observe('loaded', function (ctx, next) {
        modelName.findOne({
          where: {id : ctx.data.id},
          },function(err, someModel_instance){
                    if (err) next(err)
                    else{   
                        someModel_instance.updateAttribute(someCount,value
                            , function(err, instance){
                                console.log(done)
                        });     
                        }
                });
                next();
} );
```

This will do the trick, but the problem will be non-stop recursion that it causes. As `findOne` and `updateAttribute` will trigger the `loaded hook` again and so on. This can be resolved by using `ctx.options` field which acts like an empty container and can be used to store flags. e.g:

```
modelName.observe('loaded', function (ctx, next) {
    if(ctx.options && !ctx.options.alreadyFound){

        modelName.findOne({
          where: {id : ctx.data.id},
          },{alreadyFound = true}, function(err, someModel_instance){
                    if (err) next(err)
                    else{   
                        someModel_instance.updateAttribute(someCount,value
                            ,{alreadyFound = true}, function(err, instance){
                                console.log(done)
                        });     
                        }
                });

    }
    next();
});
```